# Как сделать DIV по высоте 100% от высоты родителя?

Tags: css

Есть страница, на которой блок #wrapper имеет минимальную высоту 100%. Как сделать блок .wrapper по высоте 100% от высоты блока #wrapper?

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
    ....    
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css:**

```
html {
    height: 100%;   
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%; // не работает
}
```

Comment: #wrapper -   height: 100%;

Comment: Задайте ширину обоим блокам.

Comment: Ширина у обоих блоков есть, она тут вряд ли играет роль. #wrapper - height: 100%; не подходит. Внутри .wrapper есть контент. При высоте контента меньше высоты окна прокрутки нет, при высоте контента больше высоты окна есть прокрутка. Поэтому используется min-height.

Comment: Честно говоря не совсем понятны причины использования min-height. В сообщении выше Вы описали поведение полосы прокрутки при тех же height: 100%, если, конечно, выше и ниже #wrapper нет никаких блоков.

Comment: Если у нас у блока есть фон, а высота height: 100%, то при контенте больше высоты окна, контент выйдет за пределы блока. Без фона конечно этого не видно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С контентом:

```css
html,
body,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis quos repudiandae animi minima earum exercitationem ipsum totam? Provident error tenetur rem et repellat non quae expedita amet. Enim quo magni repudiandae nihil illo officia sequi voluptas officiis expedita. Placeat accusantium vitae accusamus dolores repellat excepturi temporibus ducimus nihil deserunt, ad voluptate nesciunt quis quod, natus animi vero sed labore! Ipsam veritatis laborum nesciunt suscipit delectus aut eius in beatae, rerum quis quod porro et. Et soluta aut dicta nostrum, quibusdam veritatis repellat quae corporis id nemo recusandae similique quo molestiae voluptatem accusamus. Eum repellendus est, blanditiis dolorem! Quo rerum doloremque distinctio, voluptatibus numquam quisquam accusamus, ducimus obcaecati odit deserunt iure iusto repellendus libero, incidunt quasi debitis ut sequi beatae repellat. Perferendis, repellendus necessitatibus? Repellendus dolorum perferendis maxime ratione nobis id magnam fuga molestias eos deleniti sint obcaecati, impedit ipsa sed culpa assumenda quaerat exercitationem, numquam accusantium ipsam, perspiciatis sequi? Dolor saepe pariatur ratione iusto, deleniti minima! Quis inventore iure error tempora ut quo animi, non ea pariatur assumenda ipsam ab velit temporibus aliquid esse harum excepturi odit quas numquam at placeat! Adipisci, nesciunt sapiente cumque similique error est qui tenetur accusantium enim cupiditate animi voluptas, pariatur praesentium consectetur ullam sit, neque odio. Esse, dignissimos animi eius consectetur nam, hic aspernatur autem sequi obcaecati quisquam voluptatem explicabo. Distinctio ad iure quibusdam, vitae, consectetur reprehenderit non voluptas nesciunt accusamus nobis recusandae, suscipit magni nostrum facere autem porro sapiente, ipsum soluta dolorem mollitia magnam assumenda aliquid. Ipsa numquam odio ipsum similique dolorem labore necessitatibus voluptas eligendi aut consectetur quae qui soluta magnam amet quibusdam officia explicabo quisquam sapiente, delectus natus, dignissimos ipsam! Cum dignissimos ex reprehenderit accusantium eum nostrum sint quibusdam, molestiae nihil. Quisquam repellat officiis molestiae, eligendi nulla eos, dolorem perferendis vitae molestias vero explicabo quibusdam tempora, quis itaque unde. Amet dolore officiis, laborum at sequi, expedita repellendus quos facere reprehenderit maiores, commodi. Quibusdam nulla, dolorem numquam vitae nisi enim libero quis veniam alias, mollitia. Voluptatum, quidem, velit. Consectetur dignissimos, ipsum nesciunt totam iure numquam minima placeat ducimus dolorem aut id, nisi, obcaecati vero a enim quia corporis! Deleniti vero, ullam tempora dignissimos voluptate perferendis atque, eaque nisi omnis sed beatae perspiciatis accusantium voluptatum! Quibusdam mollitia quo voluptas tenetur neque repudiandae cupiditate enim consequatur, excepturi qui aspernatur, eos. Repellendus similique, accusamus labore velit, ut facilis, aliquid et atque consequatur sint ipsa at repudiandae nulla sed quaerat, tenetur! Rem reprehenderit ea possimus odit provident, dolor minima magnam dolores nostrum ipsam. Fuga veritatis eligendi eveniet magnam asperiores reprehenderit deleniti! Asperiores laudantium facere ipsa placeat iure quod. Labore temporibus nemo laborum quam aliquid aliquam porro debitis consequatur obcaecati recusandae, facilis fugiat incidunt repudiandae tempora quia eveniet quae pariatur dicta unde vero quo delectus! Molestiae earum omnis doloremque, est ratione magni! Culpa adipisci temporibus, iusto nostrum ullam officiis aperiam iure odit maiores excepturi perspiciatis ratione quis voluptas soluta, consequuntur vitae reiciendis modi! Libero neque dolore eveniet molestiae rerum omnis quaerat suscipit, adipisci nemo, soluta eum laudantium quis quo nihil, blanditiis qui. A, similique vel excepturi impedit expedita iure eveniet quisquam fugiat voluptatibus itaque deserunt placeat, aspernatur possimus magnam at doloremque enim, dolorem reiciendis velit? Ipsum officia ipsa ab ex odio at pariatur molestiae et, aliquam, explicabo accusantium placeat sed ut blanditiis id nemo molestias! Natus excepturi ducimus perspiciatis. Quo quis aliquid culpa animi dolores id, quidem quaerat placeat repellat. Voluptas voluptatibus sunt suscipit ab nemo unde repellat sequi laboriosam. Nemo laborum provident rem, ratione harum iusto pariatur molestiae libero alias ipsam impedit quo, distinctio magni ex quos veniam accusamus soluta, odio illum blanditiis. Nemo at neque consequatur voluptatum nihil maxime, enim animi! Inventore, repellat, reprehenderit. Eligendi maxime debitis impedit culpa consequuntur commodi, illum ducimus numquam animi iure necessitatibus unde quibusdam harum nesciunt accusantium consequatur rerum! Culpa incidunt, explicabo laboriosam esse suscipit nostrum dolores tenetur modi repudiandae? Harum dolorem rerum ipsum. Eligendi laudantium, atque quas explicabo ipsum esse illum incidunt nostrum! Ratione illo nihil ea. Ipsum rerum, ratione odit! Impedit velit aperiam architecto suscipit ducimus illo quam neque! Itaque architecto, odit repellat! Ratione officia dignissimos voluptatum dolores vero. Tempore impedit corporis magnam suscipit cum, sint esse inventore, labore nulla beatae doloribus eos! Obcaecati eaque quis ad provident numquam optio enim laborum nobis ea. Libero asperiores, qui quis quia, officiis vel porro ipsa, voluptas mollitia tenetur delectus illum fugit quod temporibus fugiat autem enim accusamus aperiam eum. Id quae repellendus sed ab, optio neque quibusdam in quos nobis similique amet quam? Voluptas quae, ipsam. Ipsa, rerum magni totam ratione beatae nemo soluta. Animi quod accusamus, alias non, maiores mollitia, et quas dolore cupiditate possimus dolorum iste! Natus laboriosam, enim vitae quis amet dignissimos voluptatum velit eligendi est sed facere porro accusantium, voluptatibus id quasi iure aliquid et, labore necessitatibus. Quibusdam neque suscipit consequuntur cum, sed. Dolor, deserunt tempore eveniet architecto numquam officia cum ratione eos non, reprehenderit fugiat nihil in ut eaque. Sapiente blanditiis quibusdam facilis culpa, nisi amet incidunt modi ab, dolores ullam nam distinctio et animi? Deserunt suscipit, maiores molestias quas veritatis. Fuga molestiae reprehenderit ea. Animi placeat vel porro asperiores deserunt labore, autem fugit voluptatum mollitia. Quisquam commodi fugit tempora nulla itaque iusto quod odio impedit culpa vel modi magnam illum deserunt, distinctio aspernatur nesciunt doloremque necessitatibus officia. Veniam ratione ipsum doloribus dolorem nulla voluptatum magnam, ab cumque excepturi ipsam incidunt, iste nobis veritatis inventore id qui quibusdam. Modi voluptatum harum distinctio porro quia cumque possimus, quibusdam dignissimos sapiente, necessitatibus, tempora quas excepturi dolorum, architecto voluptatem repellendus accusantium deserunt atque aperiam nulla blanditiis rem ipsam totam voluptatibus. Voluptate quis reprehenderit voluptatum quas, sapiente molestiae mollitia cupiditate? Voluptatem corrupti amet enim facilis in mollitia, laudantium ea, reiciendis totam id dolorem doloribus voluptatum laboriosam odit, autem iusto saepe fugit! Culpa delectus, atque porro deleniti doloribus soluta est maiores, tempora tenetur! Numquam sed id quaerat quidem. Porro, veritatis et, tempore alias cupiditate consectetur quae similique delectus quibusdam quos fugiat est, odio consequatur. Impedit esse ullam necessitatibus minima, non laborum consectetur harum iure asperiores nam provident nulla placeat maiores aut, vero debitis sed suscipit natus quasi ipsam doloribus. Voluptatum!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

С теми же стилями, но без контента:

```css
html,
body,
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У #wrapper должно быть min-height: 100%. Внутри блока .wrapper есть контент. Если контент по высоте больше окна, до высота #wrapper больше 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]